# How to improve performance of my laptop?

Tags: windows-10, performance-tuning

I have recently purchased a HP laptop with the below configuration

1. Intel i3 7th generation processor i3 7020U CPU @2.30 GHz
2. 1 TB HDD
3. 4 GB RAM
4. Windows 10 Home Edition 64 bit OS

After receiving the laptop I have installed the below softwares

1. Chrome Browser
2. Eclipse IDE
3. Zoom Meetings
4. Tomcat
5. Java 12
6. Node server
7. Visual Studio Code
8. Git
9. Winrar
10. Adobe acrobat reader
11. Notepad++

Now my laptop has become so slow that every operation is taking 5 to 10 seconds. If i switch between different windows, the application/process takes time to render. Initially it shows a white or black screen, after a minute it shows the application.

Even when I switch between different browser tabs also, the web page takes so much time to render.

When I received the laptop it came with 1 drive. Using disk management utility I have split my C drive into two drives, C and D which are now 130GB and 100GB respectively. The remaining of the 1 TB is unused.

At anytime, the cpu utilization is inbetween 40 and 75 percent. I see so many services/processes running.

Can anyone please tell me how to speed up my laptop?

P.S.

There are 6 apps, 103 background processes and 99 windows running. Chrome(4 tabs) is using about 500 MB. When idle, the cpu utilization is below 10%. 79% of memory is being utilized. There are more than 10 McAfee processes. Around 9 visual studio processes.

Comment: So what is it that is using 40 to 75 percent of your CPU? Details about your investigative steps are necessary.

Comment: The apps I have installed are using most of the CPU and memory. At any given time, I run tomcat, node server, visual studio, notepad++, eclipse ide and a browser.

Comment: Your laptop is seriously underpowered in almost every aspect. At the very least, you need much more RAM and an SSD. A faster CPU (quadcore) would also be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice :

- Because of HP ships their laptops with lots of bloatware, you should format that laptop and do a clean install of Windows 10 Home Edition 64 bit.
- Use 'Autoruns' tool which is the part of 'Sysinternal Tools' from Microsoft to disable all unnecessary startup entries and services. You can search the internet for more details.
- Check your HDD for problems which can cause slow read/writes by using a tool like 'HDtune'.
- Check your RAM for problems which can cause slow read/writes by using a tool like 'MemTest'.

If you encounter any problem about these steps feel free to write here, I'll help you.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot format my laptop because I do not have a copy of Window OS.

Comment: I have installed autoruns. How do I know which process to disable?

Comment: You can get a installation file of Windows Os from this Microsoft link. https://www.microsoft.com/tr-tr/software-download/windows10

Comment: Using autoruns I have disabled all hp services and few other services. After this I feel that the laptop has become a bit faster. I will continue using my laptop for couple of days and see if this is helping. If not I will download the OS and install a fresh copy.

Answer (score 1):

The best performance booster on any PC is ***always*** more RAM. More of that much, much rather than a more powerful CPU.

4gB seems paltry for Windows. If you don't want to upgrade RAM, would you consider switching to Linux, where that would be more than enough? It has equivalent apps for all of those you list (except for Zoom meetings, maybe - I don't know what that is).

[Are the Windows 10 minimum hardware requirements enough?](https://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/answer/Are-the-Windows-10-minimum-hardware-requirements-enough) quotes Microsoft minimum requirements as:

> RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) for 32-bit or 2 GB for 64-bit

Although [How much RAM does your Windows 10 PC really need?](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-much-ram-does-your-windows-10-pc-really-need) says

> If you use your Windows 10 computer for word processing, checking emails, browsing the internet, and playing Solitaire, you should have no problem using ***4GB*** of RAM. If you are performing all of these activities at once, however, you might experience a dip in performance.
>
> A lot of budget PCs come with 4GB of RAM as a base option, but if you plan on keeping your machine for several years, opting for 8GB of RAM is the safer bet, even if you only use it for light duties.

You can get 4gB laptop RAM for just under $20, and your laptop should be able to take 2 of those (2@4 will be cheaper than 1@8).

I really think that with 2gB your only options are more RAM or Linux, else you will forever have performance problems.

I look forward to seeing what other say.

p.s I am a fairly heavy multi-tasker & also like to run a VM which also needs RAM. I have always had 16gB in my laptop, but with my newest have 32gB. I find that I don't really need it, so 8 or 16gB  would seem to be ideal. You might want to buy one 8gB, rather than 2@4, so as to leave a slot open for second if you need it (depending on your budget).

Comment: Yes I was considering using Ubuntu. All those apps I am using on Windows are available on Ubuntu. Now that I have disabled all HP processes the machine seems to work like a charm.

Comment: Lolx! Then please post that as your answer, and accept it, to help others who read this question in future. Ubuntu is probably the most widely used Linux, so should have the most support  (we even have a site for it). There are also Windows friendly/Windows clone Linux distros. And Wine runs many Windows programs in Linux. But I still recommend more RAM :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the hard drive is your main issue here. They are outdated and usually PCs now come with SSDs or NVMEs (which is even better). There isn't much apart from things already mentioned by the top answer that you can do after buying such a laptop, as upgrading may be quite difficult. You'd need to open it up and see if attaching an NVME SSD is possible, as those are the smallest things so you might have the required place for it.

In my opinion, if you still got a chance to return this laptop then you should. Getting a laptop with an SSD will considerably improve desktop navigating performance, even with 4GB RAM. I couldn't tell it was still my PC when I upgraded from HDD to NVME SSD, and I had 8GB RAM. And even if you buy a small one such as 120GB, it is enough for windows and any casual software programs, and anything else you can store on an external HDD or SSD which you can connect via USB.

Answer (score -3):

**Browser Fix:**
 Try using Opera which has all tools Chrome can provide.
**AV Fix:**
 Try disabling your anti-virus if not needed.
**Performance Monitor:**
 Install Core Temp software to monitor heat issues.

**Disk management Fix:**
Give more space for C Drive.

Comment: _Disable anti-virus if not needed_!!! Anti-virus is always needed if you're online. That's a potentially dangerous suggestion.